# How do I Implement the length in textEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I want to count the total characters with spaces and total characters without spaces in textEdit. I understand that there's a length property in qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just invoke [toPlainText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) on the QTextEdit control and use the returned QString to get the length and character counts you need?

Comment: Yes that is all I need. 
`
int nospacecharcount = ui->textEdit->toPlainText().split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts).length(); 
`
but it is not accepting it.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, don't forget to upvote it and/or check it as accepted.